# full outer join where join key in result always has value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I wish to do a full outer join between two tables A, B joining on A.ID = B.ID.
Now, it is quite easy to include A.ID and B.ID in a result set. this will include rows where:

- A.ID is null, B.ID is not null
- B.ID is null, A.ID is not null
- A.ID and B.ID have the same value.

I want to have a third column which be equal to:

- A.ID and B.ID when they are the same value
- A.ID when A.ID has a value and B.ID is null
- B.ID when B.ID has a value and A.ID is null

How do I do this?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  It's a little basic, probably better-suited for SO, but specific and clearly expressed.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Can't speak for everyone, but suspect "lack of research"

Answer (score 8):

Use this function:

```
COALESCE( a.id, b.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, AB=ISNULL(A.ID,B.ID)
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```